# List store has 2 items while list is showing 5 items

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to implement an autocomplete field. The results are to be shown in a list. But everytime I make a search the new result is appended to the previous results. I tried clearing out the store attached to the list but it didn't work.

In debugger the store shows 2 items while the list shows many items (2 new + the items from previous search results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
list.refresh()
```

After removing the items from the attached store you need to refresh the list to tell it to load itself again.

Comment: @niks it worked for me. You might be using a different version of sencha. I am no more working in sencha. Please create a new question and share your code. Then someone could help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `removeAll()` on your store.

Eg.: Just to be sure check before removing

`var isStoreLoaded =Ext.getStore("theStore").isLoaded( );
                if(isStoreLoaded)
                {
          Ext.getStore("storeBomSearch").removeAll();

                }`

I hope this is a normal store, not a treeStore.

Comment: Are you using treeStore, because it is a Known issue. Also please share some code. We will try and achieve it.